# Save image path names in the database

Tags: python, scrapy

I have successfully crawled image data on a website with Scrapy, and save the image in a folder. but I want to save the path name of the image in the mysql database.

like the results of the spider below, I want to forward the data 'path' to the pipelines but I don't know how to select it

```
'images': [{'checksum': '75873dcc0944e29787525197648aa1a6',
             'path': 'full/91e6d13e3ad32def287f98199c8bbe1915c71773.jpg',
             'url': 'https://cdn.sindonews.net/dyn/620/content/2019/08/05/12/1426977/masa-kampanye-jadwal-pemilu-hingga-e-voting-jadi-isu-revisi-uu-pemilu-qoQ.jpg'}],
```

My pipelines.py:

```
import mysql.connector

class SkripsiPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        # dispatcher.connect(self.close_spider, signals.close_spider)
        # self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = '127.0.0.1',
            password = '',
            user = 'root',
            database = 'news'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self,item):
        self.curr.execute("INSERT INTO news_tb (url, title, author, time, crawl_time, image_urls, images, content) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(
            item['url'][0],
            item['title'][0],
            item['author'][0],
            item['time'][0],
            item['crawl_time'][0],
            item['image_urls'][0],
            item['content'][0]
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

My items.py

```
import scrapy
class SkripsiItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    time = scrapy.Field()
    crawl_time = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    content = scrapy.Field()
```

I want to save the name of the image path to the database. Anyone who is familiar with this problem, please let me know. thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images list is part of your item, you can just select it like this: `item['images'][0]['path']`.

You can add it to the pipeline by changing the store_db method as follows:

```
def store_db(self,item):
    path = item['images'][0]['path'].split('/')[1]
    self.curr.execute("INSERT INTO news_tb (url, title, author, time, crawl_time, image_urls, images, content, path) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(
        item['url'][0],
        item['title'][0],
        item['author'][0],
        item['time'][0],
        item['crawl_time'][0],
        item['image_urls'][0],
        item['content'][0],
        path
    ))
    self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: do you know how to remove the full/ in the path?

Comment: There's different ways to do it: `path.split('/')[1]`, `path.replace('full/', '')`

Comment: thank you very much for helping me, but sorry I'm still a beginner in python, I don't understand where the code will be written, in pipelines or in other .py files?